# Angular 2 Routes not working while navigating through browser URL

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I have some problems with routes for an Angular project, mainly with the third level of child routes. The routes are working prefectly while navigating on the app. (`routerLink`) and the problem arise when accessing the URL through the browser URL.

My Angular version is 2.4.0 
I am testing on dev server with `ng serve`.

For a project with the given structure,

```
.
├── photos
├── posts
├── users
│   ├── detail
│   │   ├── address
│   │   ├── family
│   │   ├── information
│   │   └── phones
│   ├── friends
│   └── profile
└── videos
```

The following is the code,

```
// user routes
export const userRoutes : Routes = [
  {
    path: 'detail',
    component: DetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'friends',
    component: FriendsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent
  }
]

//app routes
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'photos',
    component: PhotosComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'posts',
    component: PostsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UserListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:username',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: userRoutes
  },
  {
    path: 'videos',
    component: VideosComponent
  }
]
export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
```

and is registered as,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // declarations
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutes
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So the Application works well with the RouterLink

```
[routerLink]="['/user', username, 'detail']
```

but when I navigate the browser `<host>/user/myuser/detail` it raise exception

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DetailComponent'
```

Whats wrong? Thanks.

NB: I have setup `<router-outlet>` and is working perfectly on routerLink and the problem arises when the navigate through full url in browser.

Comment: have you added the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in you root component template ? if not put it inside your `AppComponent` template where the html will load

Comment: I have multiple `router-outlet`s  one on app component, one on user component  and one on detail component

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm supposing that when you're navigating from `user/:username/` to `/user/:username/detail` you need your `UserComponent` to hide everything that's on his template and show the `DetailComponent`

So to achieve that you'll need a component that will load its children component :

**parent.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**routes.ts**

Now let's set the routes so that `user/:username/` will load in the parent component

```
// user routes
export const userRoutes : Routes = [
 {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent // the '' path will load UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'detail',
    component: DetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'friends',
    component: FriendsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent
  }
]

//app routes
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'photos',
    component: PhotosComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'posts',
    component: PostsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UserListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:username',
    component: ParentComponent, //This component will load its children
    children: userRoutes
  },
  {
    path: 'videos',
    component: VideosComponent
  }
]
export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
```

So, what is happening here is that when you navigate to `user/:username` `ParentComponent` is loaded then `UserComponent`loaded in parent component's outlet (since the `''` path correspond to `user/:username`)

Here is a working example : **[Github](https://github.com/YounesM/routeChild)**

When you access `user/myuser`it will display : user works !
`user/myuser/details` will display : details works ! as you can see below (Without using a routerlink)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `<base href="/">?`

What is your backend? In case a user first navigates to a full URL of the subpage of your application(e.g. www.mysite.com/users/john-doe) and your backend does not return the angular 2 bootstrapped page(index.html with the bootstrap scripts), then the angular router will never kick in, although I think this is not the issue in your case, since you are getting an error from angular.

I have my .net core backend set to always return index.html for requests that are not static files, so it always properly loads the app and uses the angular routing.

Comment: I have set the `base href` (its an angular cli project). the server is local dev server with `ng serve`.

Answer (score 0):

use `<base href="/">` inside into  tag.
**Note** `<base href="/">`  it should be top inside head tag.

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
 other css and jquery ...
</head>
```

Routing like

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'Admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [

            {
                path: 'CandidateInfo',
                component: CandidateInfoComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'RptCandidateInfo',
                component: RptCandidateInfoComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'RptCandidateInfoDT',
                component: RptCandidateDTInfoComponent
            }
        ]
    },
];
```

**Its working fine.**

Answer (score -3):

Use this code in html routerLink="/user" and please mention your path in routing.ts and when u click this routerlink it will jump to concerned link

Comment: and main file use below code <router-outlet></router-outlet> as well

Comment: Its working well with routerLink and the issue is while navigating through the    browser URL. **Which has nothing to do with the routerLink**